# Search in files with detail check

Tags: c#, wpf, directory, ienumerable

I want to search all the files in the folder and subfolders And find files that have specific details How can I do this?
I use the following method, but in this method, I have to wait until all the files are received, Then check their details with loop But it does take a lot of time when I have more than 1000 files

```
AllofItems = GetFileList(@"\myfolder").ToArray();
foreach (var item in AllofItems)
{
    var file = ShellFile.FromFilePath(item); // for example C:\myfolder\1.jpg
    if(file.Properties.System.Title.Value.Equal("Empty")){
        coverView.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

and this is `GetFileList` func

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFileList(string rootFolderPath)
{
    Queue<string> pending = new Queue<string>();
    pending.Enqueue(rootFolderPath);
    string[] tmp;
    while (pending.Count > 0)
    {
        rootFolderPath = pending.Dequeue();
        try
        {
            tmp = Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath);
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException) { continue; }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return tmp[i];
        }
        tmp = Directory.GetDirectories(rootFolderPath);
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
        {
            pending.Enqueue(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do this at the same time. Check the file detail when searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [DirectoryInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) has useful methods for this.

```
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\myBaseFolder");
FileInfo[] allfiles = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

This will automatically include all subdirectories.

You could take advantage of the `await` keyword like this

```
private static async Task<FileInfo[]>  GetFileList(string rootFolderPath)
{
    FileInfo[] allfiles;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(rootFolderPath);
        allfiles = dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    });
    return allfiles;
}
```

and call it like this

```
FileInfo[] allFiles = await GetFileList(@"\myfolder");
```

and don't forget to add the `async` keyword to the method doing this call.

Comment: tnx can you write this code async? i have 9000 files and my app hangs